# Draw multiline in canvas HTML5 using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, drawing, line

I want to draw a multiline (I mean some consecutive lines that share one coordinate with the previous and one with the next line) on mouse clicks. I have currently achieved this through `mousemove` event in jQuery:

```
var worksheetCanvas = $('#worksheet-canvas');

var context = worksheetCanvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

var mouse = {
     x: -1,
     y: -1
}

var parentOffset = $('#canvas-holder').parent().offset();
worksheetCanvas.click(function(e) {

    mouse.x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);

    $(this).mousemove(function(k) {

        context.strokeStyle = "rgb(180,800,95)";

        context.lineTo(k.pageX - parentOffset.left, k.pageY - parentOffset.top);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();

    })

})​
```

But as I can show you in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/z6uFz/), when I move my mouse cursor, it leaves a trail of lines, which somehow I need to delete to create the impression of one single movable line which needs another point to be defined. I have tried to clear the unneeded lines, but the 2d context only has an `clearRect()` method, whereas I'm looking for something like `clearPath()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not `clearPath` method according to the [canvas reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_canvas.asp)

However, you are not going to need it anyways. If my assumptions are right, all you need to do is to store the values of previous strokes into an array:

I made a **[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hLFg5/)** so you can see it working and play around with it.

Clearing the canvas on every move is very effective and no performance issue.

**Source Code with Explanations**

```
$(function() {

var worksheetCanvas = $('#worksheet-canvas');

var context = worksheetCanvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
var clicked = false;

// maximum number of consecutive lines to be drawn
var maxLines = 5;

// The array of stored lines
var storedLines = [];

// The object for the last stored line
var storedLine = {};
var mouse = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
}

var parentOffset = $('#canvas-holder').parent().offset();
worksheetCanvas.click(function(e) {
    clicked = true;

    mouse.x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

    context.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);

    // Push last line to the stored lines

    if (clicked) {
        storedLines.push({
            startX: storedLine.startX,
            startY: storedLine.startY,
            endX: mouse.x,
            endY: mouse.y
        });

    }

    // set last line coordinates

    storedLine.startX = mouse.x;
    storedLine.startY = mouse.y;

    $(this).mousemove(function(k) {
        if (storedLines.length > maxLines) {
            storedLines.shift();
        }

        // clear the canvas

        context.clearRect(0, 0, 960, 500);
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "rgb(180,800,95)";

        // draw the stored lines

        for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
            var v = storedLines[i];
            context.moveTo(v.startX, v.startY);
            context.lineTo(v.endX, v.endY);
            context.stroke();
        }
        context.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        context.lineTo(k.pageX - parentOffset.left, k.pageY - parentOffset.top);
        context.stroke();

        context.closePath();


    })

})

})​
```

Comment: I think you mean `multi > maxLines + 1` and `multi--`, because the first click doesn't produce a line yet. http://jsfiddle.net/z6uFz/5/

Comment: There was something wrong with that count, right. I thought now it's not really needed, array.length can be used right there - updated the answer.

Comment: Why have you limited the number of the lines that go into the array with `var maxLines = 5`? Does it consume many resources if I don't limit it?

Comment: It can consume resources quite heavily, yes, but you can experiment with it and see where it starts to hurt. `maxLines = 5;` was only a suggestion, feel free to play around (make a fork of the jsfiddle to have your own version)

Comment: @menislici: Another possibility could be using `getImageData`/`putImageData`. That would require a constant amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to want to use two stacked canvases. The top layer will have the dynamic line (so can clearRect the whole thing on each mousemove) and then on click, you stroke onto the lower canvas